# Undefined Symbols for Architecture i386?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When building in xCode, it works in simulator for iPhone 5s, 6, 6s, etc. but when building for iPhone 5, I get a "Build Failed" with the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyGameCenterManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>         objc-class-ref in CompleteScene.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Any fix of this? Your responses are greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: Yes but have not seen any answers as to why it only happens with iPhone 5.